# JSON unmarshalling using jaxb

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jaxb

I have an application and I want it to accept both XML and JSON ,  this is my POJO

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


// Class to marshall and unmarshall the XML and JSON to POJO

 // This is a class for the request JSON and XML


@XmlRootElement
public class KeyProvision {

    private String Consumer ; 
    private String API ; 
    private String AllowedNames ; 


    public void setConsumer( String Consumer)
    {
        this.Consumer= Consumer;

    }


    public void setAPI( String API){

        this.API = API;

    }


    public void setAllowedNames(String AllowedNames){

        this.AllowedNames = AllowedNames;

    }

     @XmlElement(name="Consumer")
    public String  getConsumer(){

        return Consumer;
    }

     @XmlElement(name="API")
    public String getAPI(){

        return API;
    }

     @XmlElement(name="AllowedNames")
    public String getAllowedNames(){

        return AllowedNames;
    }

}
```

My rest interface is

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@POST
     @Path("/request")
     @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
     public Response getRequest(KeyProvision keyInfo){

    /* StringReader reader = new StringReader(keyInfo); // this code just leads to an execution failure for some reason 
     try{
         JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(KeyProvision.class);

         Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
         KeyProvision api = (KeyProvision) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
         System.out.println(api);

     }   catch(JAXBException e){
         e.printStackTrace();

     }
      */

     String result = "Track saved : " + keyInfo;
     return Response.status(201).entity(result).build() ;

  //   return "success" ;

 }
```

my XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<KeyProvision>
<Consumer> testConsumer </Consumer>
<API>posting</API>
<AllowedNames> google</AllowedNames>
</KeyProvision>
```

my JSON is

```
{
    "KeyProvision": {
        "Consumer": "testConsumer",
        "API": "posting",
        "AllowedNames": "google",

    }
}
```

My problems/questions are

1) I keep getting an 415 error when I use the JSON , why is this not unmarshalling properly?

my dependencies are

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

I set up the header as `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: 415 is media unsupported, are you setting up the content type in your request?

Comment: When you try Json from the client - are you setting the Accept header to "application/json" - because your default order is xml first then json - so unless you specifically ask for json, the resource class will default to xml.

Comment: @mikemil yes , I set the header to application/json . Infact I know it accepts it because if I change the method to accept a string instead of the object I can see the request as a String . There is a problem with the unmarshalling

Comment: Just another thought - it looks like you are returning a String - the field is 'result' not the KeyProvision.

Comment: @mikemil I am confused on why the return type would be the issue , The problem I face is with the unmarshalling . It is important for me to get the info . the return type could  be anything

Comment: The XML is working. 415 error is supposed to be a media type error (ie Content-Type not properly defined).

Comment: @user1801279, how do you test your REST api ? Through command line tool or through a browser ? Could you provde us how you set Content-Type in the header.

Comment: Please post the HTTP headers you are sending from your client.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a guess that you are not setting the content type correctly on your http request which you are sending to the service.

I dont know what tool you are using for creating a request i would recommend:

- Cmd line - curl. you just cant beat it! Chrome
- [Advanced Rest
  Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). Simply the best when working with rest services.

Both of these will allow you to see the raw http request and response and thus diagnose your problem.

Generall as a rule of thumb a space between colon and value when setting a request header is preferable. i.e

```
Content-Type: application/json;
```

So a sample curl request would look like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"KeyProvision":{"Consumer":"testConsumer","API":"posting","AllowedNames":"google"}}' http://localhost:8080/request
```

Curl will then spit out both raw request and response so you can clearly see what's happening. Advanced rest client does same but also got many tools for remembering and viewing responses/requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

More info [Jersey JSON Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html)